# Как называется человек, способный на подлость?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика, синонимы, др.-русский

Как назвать человека, способного на низкий и аморальный поступок?

Comment: Подлец + синонимы

Answer (score 4):

Хочу предложить (кроме очевидного слова "подлец" с синонимами) подходящие, как мне кажется, *определения* к человеку, который *способен* на низкие, аморальные поступки.

[Гнилой](http://endic.ru/academic/Gnilo-78124.html) человек
Для правления царством потребен не такой, как я, **гнилой** человек. [П. И. Ковалевский. Петр Великий и его гений (1900-1910)]

[Дрянной](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) человек
Когда Миша спросил ее о Филине, она плюнула и сердито загудела: «Не знаю и знать не хочу! **Дрянной** человек». [Анатолий Рыбаков. Кортик (1946-1948)]

[Скверный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) человек
Не надо прощать таким людям. Он **негодный, скверный** человек. Не нужен он здесь. [Чингиз Айтматов. Белый пароход (1970)]

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, подходящее слово — **подлец** (подлый, низкий, бесчестный человек, негодяй), см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86). Что касается синонимов, то их достаточно много, — приведу лишь несколько более-менее близких по смыслу и интересных слов.

1. **Проходимец** — человек, способный на всякие нечестные поступки, мошенник (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86)).
2. **Негодяй** — человек, совершающий подлые (негодные), асоциальные поступки (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B9)).
3. **Пройдоха** — пронырливый, хитрый, жуликоватый, не очень честный человек (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0)).
4. **Прохвост** — непорядочный человек, подлец, негодяй (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82)).
5. **Плут** — ловкий и хитрый обманщик, нечестный в отношениях с людьми человек (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%82)).
6. **Прощелыга** — пройдоха, плут, мошенник (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B0)).
7. **Сквернавец** — скверный, подлый человек, мерзавец (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86)).
8. **Выжига** — плут, пройдоха, прижимистый человек (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)).
9. **Шельма** или **шельмец** — ловкий, хитрый, плутоватый, нечестный человек, пройдоха (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0)).
10. **Шаромыга** или **шаромыжник** — человек, любящий поживиться на чужой счёт, жулик, обманщик (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B0)).

Comment: Shi, это я случайно промахнулся и заминусовал ответ. Чтобы вернуть плюсик, пришлось залезть в правку, а то система просто так не дает.

Comment: Ничего, спасибо за оценку:)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, а если вновь нажать на плюс, минус не уйдет?

Comment: @Серж  Не помню точно, в течение какого времени можно отменить или исправить голосование – то ли минута, то ли меньше. А потом – только после изменения ответа/вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже путался и тут же исправлял. Поэтому спросил.

Answer (score 0):

**Иуда, Иудушка, сукин сын, скользкий** (о мужчинах); **сукины дети** (собирательно о мужчинах и женщинах). **Скользким** называют ту неприятную разновидность, чья  ненадёжность улавливается одним лишь твоим нутром, или исходя из печального личного опыта (или из не менее печальных недоверчивости и опаски). При этом **скользкий**  выказывает своё дружелюбие, угодливость, напрашивается тебе в друзья, заискивает и т.п. Никогда не слышал, чтобы это определение применяли к женщинам. Но в некоторых контекстах само слово "женщина (*груб.* баба (*))" подразумевает готовность предать (из страха, ради личной выгоды) и вероломство. В "Пословицах русского народа" В.И. Даля находим: **Волос долог, а язык длинней. Меж бабьим да и нет не проденешь иголки. Перекати-поле - бабий ум (известная трава, которая катится полем по ветру). Баба да бес - один у (в) них вес. Вольна баба в языке, а чёрт - в бабьем кадыке. Женские умы - что татарские сумы** (т.е. перемётны)

Ещё из Даля:
**Он тебя и обует и разует. Он тебя напоит и вытрезвит. Он тебя угостит, что нагишом домой уйдешь. Он тебя и купит, и продаст. Здравствуй, женившись, да не с кем жить! Не ищи правды в других, коли в тебе её нет. Мастеровой не худ, да в душе плут. Коли не врёт, так правду говорит.**

Ещё про таких слышал:
Он (она) **родную мать/ родного отца предаст.**

(*) - известно, что "бабой" в осуждающем смысле называют так или иначе женоподобных мужчин ("слабаков," болтунов, сплетников, трусов и т.д.)

Comment: *– Год брака – внушительный опыт, поэтому я склонен поверить вам на слово и согласиться с вашим мнением об Анне Честертон. Весьма **скользкая особа**. Была бы хоть малейшая улика против неё, я бы уже мчался обратно в особняк Шоу с наручниками* (А. М. Серегова. Вызовите шерифа). *Мерзкая, **скользкая тётка**...* (из толкового словаря русской разговорной речи).